# can i see room availability for meetings i did not create?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I get many meetings involving people abroad my country. They create the meeting with a meeting room in their country, but not mine. So I need to reserve a room for myself. This can be done by forwarding the meeting to the room email. However, before that, I need to see which room is available (I don't want to blindly forward to all because then several might be available and I'll need to cancel)

What's the best way to see all my rooms and which is available? Opening the meeting doesn't show the rooms (this is how it is in Outlook for Mac, which is nice), so right now I create a new meeting, set it to the same date&time as the original, find a room, then forward the original meeting to the room. This is of course cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook 2013 only has one field for location. There's no feature to book two separate rooms. You are essentially booking two meeting rooms because of the remote location and local location.